# Packet analyzers: how do they work?

Tags: packet-sniffers, sniffer

I've been quite interested in IT security for a long time and I've come across network snfifers several time. What I don't understand is how the process actually works. Let's assume we have a wireless network. Computer A requests an external website, going through the router. Computer B, which has the sniffer, captures the packages going through the local network. If that's the basic process, how can it capture a packet?
Do you have to setup a fake router and sniff all traffic passing through, or can you just connect to a wireless network and start sniffing?

If you feel like explaining the process in detail, or link to a guide, that'd be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A sniffer is *a computer program or a piece of computer hardware that can intercept and log traffic passing over a digital network or part of a network.*

The normal process is for a Computer B connect to the network it wants to sniff and start capturing packets. Then if needed, it decodes the packet's raw data, showing the values of various fields in the packet, and analyzes its content according to the appropriate RFC or other specifications.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "how to sniff wireless networks" is "it depends" (upon the OS and hardware being used, whether you want to see wireless management and low-level control packets or just the normal data packets, etc, etc).

[Wireshark Wiki: WLAN Capture Setup](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) gives lots of detailed info.

See also [Wireshark Wiki: Capture Setup](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup) .

In general, sniffing on Machine A will capture the normal data packets from/to Machine A. You *may* be able to capture the wireless management packets & etc.

To capture wireless traffic to/from Machine A using a machine other than Machine A,

1. Special hardware is required: See "Airpcap";  or
2. That Machine needs access to the traffic in some manner.

   For example: a "monitor" port on the wireless router can used (if available).

   Or: if a wireless router is connected to a wired network via an Ethernet connection, 
   then a tap can be inserted into the Ethernet connection.

   or  ....

Comment: AirPcap is needed *on Windows* *with WinPcap-based applications*, and that's because WinPcap doesn't support NDIS 6 and can't put Wi-Fi adapters in monitor mode on Windows.  Microsoft Network Monitor uses a different driver that supports NDIS 6 and *can* put adapters into monitor mode, but many adapters have drivers that don't handle that.  On Linux, \*BSD, and OS X, either libpcap *can* put adapters into monitor mode or you can do it outside the application, so that's not a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Sniffing the traffic is actually pretty straightforward thing. For example, for WiFi sniffing a standard adapter implementing the 802.11 protocol is sufficient for the HW part. In addition the device driver & firmware must support sniffing mode. The only principal difference between normal and sniffing mode is the packet filtering. Normally, the device SW will drop the traffic not directed to it by checking the destination MAC address. In sniffer mode it will accept all traffic and pass it to upper layers for analysis.